# ggplot2 stacked bar chart: each bar is one colour, stacked groups are shown using alpha

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Say I have the following stacked bar chart:

```
# Load library
library(ggplot2) 

# Convert to factors
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl) 

# Plot results
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=gear, fill=cyl) ) + geom_bar() 
print(p)
```

which gives,

[image]

In this plot, each group (i.e., `cyl`) is a different colour and all bars are the same colour scheme. Now, what I'd like to do is have each bar as a single, different colour, but the groups are designated by alpha. For example, bars for `gear` values of 3, 4, and 5 may be red, blue, and green, respectively, and `cyl` values are depicted by alpha values of 1, 0.75, and 0.5, respectively. This way the bar for, say, `gear` equals 3 is all the same colour (red), but the `cyl`s are shown as different shades. Is this possible?

The code below implements the alpha values:

```
# Function for adding alphas
alpha_bar <- function(x)ifelse(x == 4, 1, ifelse(x == 6, 0.75, ifelse(x == 8, 0.5, NA)))

# Add alphas
mtcars$alpha <- alpha_bar(mtcars$cyl)

# Plot results
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=gear, fill=cyl, alpha = alpha) ) + geom_bar() 
print(p)
```

This gets the alpha values correct. However, if I try to change the colours of each bar using something like this,

```
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

it changes the colours of the `cyl` values rather than `gear` values. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map both attributes:

```
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=gear, alpha=cyl,  fill=gear) ) + geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CD3700", "#9ACD32", "#00868B"))
p
```

Keep in mind that mapping alpha values this way is considered to be bad visualizing of data. Why? Just look at the guide for `cyl`.

[image]